# install cairo and libcairo2 on CentOS

Tags: r, cairo

I searched and could not really find an answer for this. I have a CentOS server that does not have and RHN connectivity. I need to install cairo and libcairo2 to make rapache work. I did find the cairo tar file, and installed it sucessfully. When I attempted to install R cairo package, it failed with this error:

```
      R CMD INSTALL -l /usr/local/lib64/R/library  Cairo_1.5-1.tar.gz
      error: checking whether Cairo programs can be compiled... configure: error: Cannot compile a simple Cairo program. See config.log for details.
```

Someone suggested that I'm missing libcairo2 package. I searched all over the place and cannot find this package for centos. Any ideas? P.S. I tried to install the R cairo package within R, the same exact error.

locate libcairo output:

```
    /usr/lib/libcairo.so.2
     /usr/lib/libcairo.so.2.9.2
     /usr/lib64/libcairo.a
     /usr/lib64/libcairo.so
    /usr/lib64/libcairo.so.2
    /usr/lib64/libcairo.so.2.9.2
    /usr/local/lib/libcairo-script-interpreter.a
   /usr/local/lib/libcairo-script-interpreter.la
   /usr/local/lib/libcairo-script-interpreter.so
    /usr/local/lib/libcairo-script-interpreter.so.2
    /usr/local/lib/libcairo-script-interpreter.so.2.11000.0
    /usr/local/lib/libcairo.a
    /usr/local/lib/libcairo.la
    /usr/local/lib/libcairo.so
    /usr/local/lib/libcairo.so.2
    /usr/local/lib/libcairo.so.2.11000.0
    /usr/local/lib/cairo/libcairo-trace.a
    /usr/local/lib/cairo/libcairo-trace.la
   /usr/local/lib/cairo/libcairo-trace.so
   /usr/local/lib/cairo/libcairo-trace.so.0
   /usr/local/lib/cairo/libcairo-trace.so.0.0.0
```

I see these type of errors in config.log file:

```
configure:3631: checking whether Cairo programs can be compiled
configure:3645: gcc -std=gnu99 -o conftest -g -O2  -I/usr/local/include/cairo   conftest.c  -L/usr/local/lib -lcairo >&5

/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_set_write_user_transform_fn'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_set_bKGD'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_get_valid'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_set_write_fn'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_get_error_ptr'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_set_filler'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_read_update_info'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_set_read_fn'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_set_packing'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_set_strip_16'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_set_tRNS_to_alpha'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_error'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_write_image'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_set_interlace_handling'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_read_end'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
/usr/local/lib/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `png_read_image'
```

Comment: what does `locate libcairo` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `locate` can find the library suggests that it was installed succesfully. A problem could be that although it is installed, R cannot find it. Check if the location of `libcairo.so` is in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

And to see what goes wrong, what does the file `config.log` say?

Comment: Which Cairo version did you install?